# How to get files list in OnBeforeSend event of PrimeNG file upload?

Tags: angular, file-upload, primeng

I use Primeng FileUpload.

html code:

```
<p-fileUpload (onBeforeSend)="onBeforeSend($event)" (onError)="onLoadFileError()" name="myfile" [url]="uploadUrlPrefix" multiple="multiple" chooseLabel="Choose Coordinates Files" accept=".csv"></p-fileUpload>
```

ts code:

```
onBeforeSend(event) {
  this.errorHandler.runSafelyCode(() => {
    event.xhr.setRequestHeader("SessionId", 99);
  }, "ToolsComponent:onBeforeSend");
}
```

Can I get files list inside OnBeforeSend event?

Answer (score 0):

I use this:
HTML:

```
<p-fileUpload #uploader (onBeforeUpload)="onBeforeUploadListener($event, uploader)">
</p-fileUpload>
```

JS:

```
onBeforeUploadListener(event, uploader:any){
// your have acces to files :
uploader.files
}
```